# How can I implement OneLogin SSO to my MVC website, similar to how ClassLink SSO works

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, onelogin

**Hello,**

I have request to implement SSO using three different providers: "ClassLink", "Clever" and "OneLogin".
I managed to implement SSO for "ClassLink" and "Clever" with very easy steps, however I'm finding difficulty understanding how to achieve this with "OneLogin".

The concept I expected is like what is working in ClassLink, simply redirect to Classlink login page, once the user login there it will redirect to a callback method with code, then I use that code to connect to the sso api with client-id and client-secret so that I got user info.

This concept works like a charm with "ClassLink" and "Clever" but when I wanted to work with OneLogin I found bunch of api documentation for oath, oath2, Saml, Saml2, openid, ... and when I created a developer account it asks me to add application so I add the OICD and follow the steps in documentation but I got nothing.

All what I expected is a sandbox account with one fake user, login url and callback url so that I can implement SSO and try to login with that user, but I did not make any progress.

Any help please will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I have to do the same thing with ClassLink but having some trouble. How do you test it? I can't find any way to simulate a user logging into ClassLink, so I can see if the code is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the OneLogin support and they were very responsive and helped me solve my issue, so for any one have similar issue the only way to solve it is by contacting the support team.

Comment: Please help me with "Clever"! The SSO post request is not working and I can't find answers